# Horizontal Timer with Swipper issue

Tags: javascript, css

How to remove horizontal line before first element and after last element in horizontal timer with swipper implementation in below article, i removed left:42% in css, so it is shifted left to remove left horizontal but right horizontal line is not able to remove -

```
.status span:before {
 content: '';
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
background-color: #e8eeff;
border-radius: 25px;
border: 4px solid #3e70ff;
position: absolute;
top: -15px;
**left: 0%;**
transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}
```

[codepen Horizontal Timeline swipper](https://codepen.io/elize15leite/pen/RwNYLwO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to work with a spacer element inside of each `swiper-slide` which will be only visible inside the first and last element. It also has the same restriction as the old answer, the background needs to have a uniform color.

**HTML code**

```
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper timeline">
      <div class="swiper-slide" v-for="item in steps">
        <div class="status">
          <span>{{item.title}}</span>
          <div class="overlapper"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlapper {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 4px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -4px;
  display: none;
}

.swiper-slide:first-child .overlapper {
  left: 0;
  display: block;  
}

.swiper-slide:last-child .overlapper {
  right: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

**Codepen**

https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/XWmYyvJ

---

### Old answer

One option that only works on uni-color backgrounds would be to add "terminators" to overlap the `border-top` that is defined on the `.swiper-slide` element. It will also need some tweeking to get the right width of the `.swiper-terminator` otherwise it will overlap in the wrong spot.

**HTML Code**

```
 <div class="swiper-wrapper timeline">
  <div class="swiper-terminator swiper-left"></div>
  <div class="swiper-slide" v-for="item in steps">
    <div class="status">
      <span>{{item.title}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-terminator swiper-right"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.swiper-terminator.swiper-left {
  left: 0;
}

.swiper-terminator.swiper-right {
  right: 0;
}

.swiper-terminator {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.status span {
  /* Add the z-index to position the bubble over the terminator */
  z-index: 3;
}

.timeline {
  position: relative;
}
```

**Codepen**

https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/KKderQx

Answer (score 1):

Since the line is the border of the element with the text, it can never get smaller than the element/text itself.

I´d suggest to use an extra element with the width you need instead of the border.

To do this just remove the line

```css
border-top: 4px solid #3e70ff;
```

from your css-class `.status` and add the following css classes:

```css
.status:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #3e70ff;
}
.swiper-slide:first-of-type .status:before {
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.swiper-slide:last-of-type .status:before {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution and works fine in a Codepen: https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/VwvdNXQ. Should be the accepted solution!